# Unable to remove AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler class or sufficiently cover it with a test class

Tags: apex, community

Discovered this class during prod. deploy as it has 0% coverage as it is being unused.

I double checked my community and we are using Default pages for everything and a configurable self-reg page for registration (As far as I can tell this class is not used for that process).

However, upon trying to remove this class via destructive changes I get the following error:

**classes/AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler1585607343353.cls -- Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.  Remove the usage and try again. : Community Discoverable Login - 7ov6g000000blOy.**

I believe this was generated when I was initially trying to use a discovery page for something but had since moved on from that approach. Am I missing something?

Lastly, I did try to cover this generated and untouched class in an attempt to not have my code coverage plummet with this 0% covered class and provided inputs to the login(String identifier, String startUrl, Map requestAttributes) method passing in null for the startUrlr and an empty map but could not get anywhere, with the class returning the following error:

**Auth.LoginDiscoveryException: No Passwordless Login redirect URL returned for verification method: PASSWORD" and am not sure how to proceed on that front either.**

Preferably, I would much rather delete this class but am not sure where it could be being referenced given that I only have 1 community and there are no discoverable pages being used and from what I have read and understood, the self-reg page does not have anything to do with this class.

Appreciate any and all who help!

The auto generated class:

```
// This auto-generated class contains the default logic for login discovery by SMS or email. 
// You can customize the code to ensure it meets your needs. The requestAttributes parameter 
// provides additional information you can use in the discovery logic. Attributes include CommunityUrl, 
// IpAddress, UserAgent, and location information (such as Country and City). 

global class AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler1585607343353 implements Auth.LoginDiscoveryHandler {

  global PageReference login(String identifier, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
    if (identifier != null && isValidEmail(identifier)) {
      // Search for user by email 
      List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = :identifier AND IsActive = TRUE];
      if (!users.isEmpty() && users.size() == 1) {
        // User must have verified email before using this verification method. We cannot send messages to unverified emails. 
        // You can check if the user has email verified bit on and add the password verification method as fallback.
        List<TwoFactorMethodsInfo> verifiedInfo = [SELECT HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress FROM TwoFactorMethodsInfo WHERE UserId = :users[0].Id];
        if (!verifiedInfo.isEmpty() && verifiedInfo[0].HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress == true) {
          // Use email verification method if the user's email is verified.
          return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL, startUrl, requestAttributes);
        } else {
          // Use password verification method as fallback if the user's email is unverified.
          return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.PASSWORD, startUrl, requestAttributes);
        }
      } else {
        throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No unique user found. User count=' + users.size());
      }
    }
    if (identifier != null) {
      String formattedSms = getFormattedSms(identifier);
      if (formattedSms != null) {
        // Search for user by SMS 
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE MobilePhone = :formattedSms AND IsActive = TRUE];
        if (!users.isEmpty() && users.size() == 1) {
          // User must have verified SMS before using this verification method. We cannot send messages to unverified mobile numbers. 
          // You can check if the user has mobile verified bit on or add the password verification method as fallback.
          List<TwoFactorMethodsInfo> verifiedInfo = [SELECT HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber FROM TwoFactorMethodsInfo WHERE UserId = :users[0].Id];
          if (!verifiedInfo.isEmpty() && verifiedInfo[0].HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber == true) {
            // Use SMS verification method if the user's mobile number is verified.
            return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.SMS, startUrl, requestAttributes);
          } else {
            // Use password verification method as fallback if the user's mobile number is unverified.
            return discoveryResult(users[0], Auth.VerificationMethod.PASSWORD, startUrl, requestAttributes);
          }
        } else {
          throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No unique user found. User count=' + users.size());
        }
      }
    }
    if (identifier != null) {
      // You can customize the code to find user via other attributes, such as SSN or Federation ID
    }
    throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('Invalid Identifier');
  }

  private boolean isValidEmail(String identifier) {
    String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';
    // source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html 
    Pattern EmailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);
    Matcher EmailMatcher = EmailPattern.matcher(identifier);
    if (EmailMatcher.matches()) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  }

  private String getFormattedSms(String identifier) {
    // Accept SMS input formats with 1 or 2 digits country code, 3 digits area code and 7 digits number
    // You can customize the SMS regex to allow different formats
    String smsRegex = '^(\\+?\\d{1,2}?[\\s-])?(\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{4})$';
    Pattern smsPattern = Pattern.compile(smsRegex);
    Matcher smsMatcher = SmsPattern.matcher(identifier);
    if (smsMatcher.matches()) {
      try {
        // Format user input into the verified SMS format '+xx xxxxxxxxxx' before DB lookup
        // Append US country code +1 by default if no country code is provided
        String countryCode = smsMatcher.group(1) == null ? '+1' : smsMatcher.group(1);
        return System.UserManagement.formatPhoneNumber(countryCode, smsMatcher.group(2));
      } catch(System.InvalidParameterValueException e) {
        return null;
      }
    } else { return null; }
  }

  private PageReference getSsoRedirect(User user, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
    // You can look up if the user should log in with SAML or an Auth Provider and return the URL to initialize SSO.
    return null;
  }

  private PageReference discoveryResult(User user, Auth.VerificationMethod method, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
    //Only external users with an External Identity or community license can login using Site.passwordlessLogin
    //Use getSsoRedirect to enable internal user login for a community
    PageReference ssoRedirect = getSsoRedirect(user, startUrl, requestAttributes);
    if (ssoRedirect != null) {
      return ssoRedirect;
    } else {
      if (method != null) {
        List<Auth.VerificationMethod> methods = new List<Auth.VerificationMethod>();
        methods.add(method);
        PageReference pwdlessRedirect = Site.passwordlessLogin(user.Id, methods, startUrl);
        if (pwdlessRedirect != null) {
          return pwdlessRedirect;
        } else {          
          throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No Passwordless Login redirect URL returned for verification method: ' + method);
        }
      } else {
        throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No method found');
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

My test class - the last line is invoking the auto-generated class:

```
@isTest
private class TEST_AutoGenCommunityClasses {
    @testSetup
    static void dataCreation(){
        //insert account
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account'
        );

        insert(acc);                

         //insert contact
         Contact cont = new Contact(
            LastName = 'Test',
            AccountId = acc.Id,
            Email = 'uniqueabc@xyz.com'
        );

        insert(cont);

        Id profileId;
        for(Profile pro : [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Customer Community Plus User']){
            profileId = pro.Id;
        }  

        User usr = new User(
            LastName = 'FIrst',
            FirstName='Last',
            Alias = 'testFi',
            Email = 'uniqueabc@xyz.com',
            Username = 'abc@xyz.com.deloitte.changescout.portal',
            ProfileId = profileId,
            ContactId = cont.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
        );
        insert(usr);
    }

    @isTest static void testComms() {        
        AutocreatedConfigSelfReg1585609620767 comm = new AutocreatedConfigSelfReg1585609620767(); 
        Id accId;

        for(Account acc : [select Id from Account where Name = 'Test Account']){
            accId = acc.Id;
        }

        Id profileId;
        for(Profile pro : [select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator']){
            profileId = pro.Id;
        }        
        comm.createUser(accId, profileId, new Map<SObjectField, String>(), null);

        AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler1585607343353 commDisc = new AutocreatedDiscLoginHandler1585607343353();

        String email = 'uniqueabc@xyz.com';

        commDisc.login(email,null,new Map<String, String>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically your unit tests should work. Can you maybe post your class and unit tests that you made?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kurunve, I have updated my question with the relevant classes.